# Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead sort by value from JSON

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I need to display the results based on the values from JSON retrieved from server.

Example Json:

```
[{
    "keyword"   :    "Google Plus",
    "value"     :    10
},{
    "keyword"   :    "Google",
    "value"     :    3
}]
```

By default Bootstrap does this:

Textbox: Goog

Suggestions:

1- Google

2- Google Plus

However I need "Google Plus" to come up first since it has a higher value.

I am using Angular.js if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, angular matters!

If you are using angular, sorting can be done based on the value, like as in [this example](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04).

If you are keen to do it in reverse ( descending ) you should refer to [orderBy Angular API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy).

So in your controller, you should put negative sign ( see below ) :

```
$scope.orderProp = '-value';
```

And/Or if you are prefer to do it in your html ( if you are using "li" ) you should mentioned reversed for descending.

```
<ul class="items">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items| filter:query | orderBy:value:reverse">
    {{item.keyword}}
  </li>
</ul>
```